# Ng-build working but only showing..Loading AppComponent content here

Tags: apache, angular, typescript

I am trying my first ng-build to run my project from a remote servor (Ubuntu with Apache), so I am in my local project then I do my ng build command then it create a "dist" folder. That folder I place it in my var/www/html folder without any error...so when I run my servor IP point on the index.html the only thing I can see is...Loading AppComponent content here ...

If anyone could help could be great

Here's the error I've got:

[image]

Here's my index.html generate from ng build:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>MIAMI</title>
   <base href="./">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the console and paste the error here.

Comment: @FahadNisar I've update my post

Comment: Check is there any html file in your "dist" folder?

Comment: I follow that step to make it: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#simplest-deployment-possible

Comment: For infos I uses the router in my app..I saw here that you've got  some special config about that case: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback

Comment: you are placing dist folder as it is in html or the files inside dist are placed inside html?

Comment: @EmileCantero, You can change `<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/inline.bundle.js"></script>` like this in html file and then run your application.

Comment: @FahadNisar my files are inside the dist folder who's inside the html folder

Comment: @Darshita I'll try this out right now and let you know

Comment: yup @Darshita is right.

Comment: You right guys I replace with `<script type="text/javascript" src="./inline.bundle.js"></script>` but now I 've got a different error in the console, I 've update my post

Comment: your index.html is inside dist?

Comment: @FahadNisar, yes Sir it is inside :-)

Comment: :) ok try replacing the path change with dist/inline.bundle.js etc. and place the index.html outside the dist.

Comment: Why your site's URL is starting with `file:///...`? I think it should be start with `http://...`.

Comment: @FahadNisar ahright I'll try this out and Darshita the reason it's starting from file:/// is because my apache servor is inside my computer (I'm working with Xubuntu dist)

Comment: @EmileCantero,Thnks. I am totally unaware about hosting angular application on Apache server.

Comment: @FahadNisar I move the index.html and change the path to dist/inline... and I've got that error now (I've update the picture in my post)

Comment: Such a security error Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///var/www/html/'

Comment: this might be something related to rotes configuration:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5502 Plunker really could help me identify the issue.

Comment: Hi huys @the end I found it with my lead I had to rewrite the file in etc/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.conf and write the good path then it works !!!

Comment: Gud to know that it is resolved. :)